# Are openshift docs out-dated?

Tags: openshift

I am new to openshift, I try to follow the docs on `DIY` here: https://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/oo_user_guide.html#deploying-a-sample-diy-application

It state that there is a dot folder in my home called `.openshift` that contains the hocks the I gonna use.

However, I cannot find such directory, should I create it? or the docs are out-dated?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at older docs. The current version is v3.0 and the latest documentation is at https://docs.openshift.org/latest/welcome/index.html

Comment: @MuhammadHewedy I think you're looking in the 'newest' docs for the version of OpenShift which you want to use. But this version (m4) isn't supported anymore (deprecated). Since July 2015 there is OpenShift V3 (now 3.1 already). It's working with docker and kubernetes instead of broker, geares etc.